How to handle paper soap without making my pocket dirty?
In my hostel campus soaps are rare so we have to use paper soap of our own.
It is small paper coated with soap and create foam when we rub on wet hands just like normal soap.
But when our hands are dirty/oily/wet I can’t get it out of pocket. There is also a handkerchief which makes it even more challenging to get it out.
If I keep my paper soap outside at sink then most likely someone else would use it before me.
Could someone recommend a way to keep the soap ready with me without using pockets or some way to get it out with minimal contact with pocket.

An explanation (and photo?) of what "paper soap" means would help for those of us that have never heard of it before.

Do you mean something like this?

@ShadowWizard yes definitely.

Can you give us an idea of the activities that make you dirty? You are on hostel / campus area, so heavy work seems to be excluded.

@virolino 1) washroom 2) mess 3) cadaver dissection 4) removing socks

@virolino it’s usually unpredictable because sometime I may or may not get chance to dissect. Sometimes I eat at one place sometimes at other place.

Don't you have some wash area (water, sink) close to the place where you dissect? If not, that seems quite bad, for several reasons (how do you clean removed organs for seeing details better?). If you have, then you can see if someone tries to use your soap.

For dissection we do have sinks nearby but during other medical works our hands get contaminated at uncertain times (by medicine, patients etc). In many rooms only bare feet is allowed so hands get dirty with socks. That’s why I said it’s uncertain. But I have found a trick of my own. Wait for some time, I would post my own answer to show my trick.

My hack solution is to

Tie a short string to the soap package (perhaps make a hole).
Tie the other end to a belt loop.
Put the soap pack in your pocket.
When you need the soap, pull it out with the string.


You really remind me of that joke, where the waiters at that restaurant were wearing some strings attached to their "clothes" :)))


But when our hands are dirty/oily/wet I can’t get it out of pocket.

This is the typical XY problem. You do not need a hack to extract the soap, you need to make the soap available when you need it.
And one cannot usually get dirty / oily / wet unexpectedly. It means that you have a realistic chance to make the soap available when you are still clean enough, and then use it like a normal soap when you need it.

Example: you repair your car. Obviously, you will get dirty with oils and dust and whatnot. That is why you first make sure you have the cleaning agents readily available BEFORE the repair, as well as water and towels. Only after that you start the repair.
It happens to me that I take a bath, forgetting that I just put the towels into the washing machine. Should I ask what is the hack to get myself dry without waiting and without walking naked and wet through my apartment?
The same thing about using the restroom without checking the availability of toilette paper first.

Bottom line: Even if yo do not put the soap in the bathroom / washroom from the beginning (because other might use it), before getting dirty, at least remove it from your pockets, and remove it from its protective cover (box, bag, whatever...). Or at least open the protective cover, so you have easy access to it when needed.

EDIT: Another option (inspired by @WeatherVane 's comment)
Use a 2-step approach. Keep the soap in the pocket. Keep some other material (paper tissues, towels etc.) handy. Use the cheap material first, to remove the most of the oil / dirt. Now you can get the soap out of the pocket and use it for full cleaning.

EDIT: another option
Ask someone to give you their soap. When you are clean and dry (most likely, in less than 1-2 min), give them your soap.
NOTE: I do not know how many washes are in one soap. I assume that it is mostly a one-time use (maybe 2 or 3).

I try to find secret spots where I can hide my soap. I found one in toilet and some kind soul has placed a real soap at hostel mess. But I wanted to know some “universal” method that can work everywhere.

And how can we find secret spots for you? We do not know the area where you want to hide it.

@virolino I don’t want you to find secret spot but instead tell a way to store it in more accessible way.

@virolino I use your answer when eating a snack while hiking, and my hands will become greasy. I get a tissue out before eating, and tuck it into a loop on the pack.

@WeatherVane: +1 for the comment. +1 for the answer? :)

I think OP wants it available "on demand", for example they might have been out at work for several hours.

While I'm not sure what exactly is this "paper soap", my idea is pretty generic to something small that fits in a pocket, and you don't want it to have direct contact with the pocket.
My hack is using a small zip bag:

The size of the bag is small enough to fit in pocket as well, and you can put the soap inside it.

My problem is to get it outside pocket with dirty/wet/oily hands.
